# toggleClass in Ajax request not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am having a little trouble getting my .toggleClass to work. I am very new to javascript so forgive me if im missing something really simple here. I want users to be able to favourite things like images and posts. I have a little heart icon that when clicked should turn red/black depending if they're adding/removing. Everything works apart from the .toggleClass. Can anyone point out where i am going wrong?

**index.php**

---

```
<div class="heart-box"> 
   <?php 
//Check if user has fav'd the image.. 
     $hasFav = db::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM favourites WHERE userID = ? AND img_id = ?", array($the_user, $img_id));
     $action = $hasFav->results() ? 'unfav-heart' : 'fav-heart'; 
   ?>

    <div  class="<?php echo $action; ?>  fa fa-heart" id="<?php echo $img_id; ?>" ></div>
</div>
```

---

**Script**

---

```
    $(document).ready(function(){


  //add to favourites...
  $('.fav-heart').click(function(){
    var img_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
      url: 'favourites.php',
      type: 'post',
      async: false,
      data:{
        'fav' : img_id
      },
      success:function(){ 
        $(img_id).toggleClass("unfav-heart");
      }
    });
  });
  // remove from favourites...
  $('.unfav-heart').click(function(){
    var img_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
      url: 'favourites.php',
      type: 'post',
      async: false,
      data:{
        'fav' : img_id
      },
      success:function(){ 
        $(img_id).toggleClass("fav-heart");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

---

Comment: It is a BAD practice executing a query in front-end

Comment: Uh @Matt.k that query is done with PHP on the back end before the page is rendered.

Comment: @Jay isn't it still a bad idea to have that on view ?!

Comment: We don't know what, if any, framework there is @Matt.k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery id's need a # in the selector :

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  //add to favourites...
  $('.fav-heart').click(function(){
    var img_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
      url: 'favourites.php',
      type: 'post',
      async: false,
      data:{
        'fav' : img_id
      },
      success:function(){ 
        $("#"+img_id).toggleClass("unfav-heart");
      }
    });
  });
  // remove from favourites...
  $('.unfav-heart').click(function(){
    var img_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
      url: 'favourites.php',
      type: 'post',
      async: false,
      data:{
        'fav' : img_id
      },
      success:function(){ 
        $("#"+img_id).toggleClass("fav-heart");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Holy Crap I've been stuck on this for hours all because of a #! haha. Much appreciated :)

Comment: Why use the ID at all? You have a variable that points directly to the element, use that. `var img = $(this)` in the click function, and `img.toggleClass()` in the success function.

Comment: To get an html element with X id, you have to use a # in your selector, use nothing to get elements by tag, and . to get elements by classes. 
$(this) is the element wich fired the event.
http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the other answer, you left out the `#` prefix to indicate an ID in a selector. But there's no need to use a selector at all, since you have a variable pointing directly at the element.

```
  $('.fav-heart').click(function(){
    var img = $(this);
    var img_id = this.id;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'favourites.php',
      type: 'post',
      async: false,
      data:{
        'fav' : img_id
      },
      success:function(){ 
        img.toggleClass("unfav-heart");
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: I am not using an image element. I am basically putting the id for the image in the id-attribute then posting it to a php file. That php file then queries the db along with the users id to check if it exists or not. But your answer is still useful to me because i literally have no experience with using Javascript so things like that are always handy to know! Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look at your HTML, I assumed it was an image because you called the variable `img_id`. But the type of element is irrelevant, the point is that you have a variable that contains the element, there's no need to use the ID to find it in the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Your click handlers for both selectors are registered on document ready. That's why only these elements who match the selector classes are assigned to the click handler. If you toggle the class afterwards you have to reassign the click handlers.

A better approach would be to register a click handler for all heart elements. Inside the click handler you do a switch case statement where you toggle the class accordingly.